# Tizen studio device manager opens a tiny window when clicking on anything

Tags: java, gui

I'm trying to connect to a device in tizen studio, but every time I open the device manager and click on any button a seemingly tiny (just a few pixels wide) and blank window opens and nothing happens. I can close the window by hitting 'TAB' and then 'Enter' or 'ESC', maybe it's a dialog popup or an error prompt?

[Tizen device manager with the tiny window highlighted with a circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUJkZ.png)

What I've tried so far:

- Reinstalling the software
- Reinstalling the software without plugins
- Resizing the window (could not be resized)
- Running the device manager without tizen studio running
- Running the device manager from terminal to check for errors (all i got was a regular, non-critical [GTK error](https://pastebin.com/05UZfJbg))
- Changing java version from 18 to 8

I am on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Probably a bug that should be reported to the 3rd party software devs, nothing we can address here.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Ok thanks, my bad.